# Flutter Windows app blur effect animation issue

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-windows

## When I try to run below code in windows and chrome, the blur effect is different. Images are attached below.

```
// Copyright (c) 2019, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
// for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super();

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: CurrencyCard(
          lgColors: const [
            Colors.green,
            Colors.black54,
          ],
          icon: Icons.add,
          percent: '35',
          price: '232,40',
          theme: Theme.of(context),
          iconBgColor: Colors.green,
          showChart: false,
          shadowColor: Color.alphaBlend(Colors.green, Colors.amber),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CurrencyCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color iconBgColor, shadowColor;

  const CurrencyCard({
    super.key,
    required this.lgColors,
    required this.iconBgColor,
    required this.icon,
    required this.percent,
    required this.price,
    required this.theme,
    required this.shadowColor,
    this.showChart = true,
  });

  final List<Color> lgColors;
  final IconData icon;

  final String price, percent;
  final ThemeData theme;

  final bool showChart;

  @override
  State<CurrencyCard> createState() => _CurrencyCardState();
}

class _CurrencyCardState extends State<CurrencyCard> {
  double elevation = 16;
  var angle = 0.0;

  var position = const Offset(0, 0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MouseRegion(
      onHover: (event) => setState(() {
        elevation = 48;
        angle = 0.1;
        position = event.localPosition.translate(-54, -54);
      }),
      onExit: (event) => setState(() {
        elevation = 16;
        angle = 0;
      }),
      child: Transform(
        transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(angle),
        filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        child: Card(
          elevation: elevation,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
          ),
          shadowColor: widget.shadowColor,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width * 0.4,
            height: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height * 0.3,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
              gradient: SweepGradient(
                colors: widget.lgColors,
                center: Alignment.topRight,
                stops: const [0.2, 0.3],
              ),
            ),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                /// blur effect on top of card wherever mouse goes
                if (elevation == 48)
                  Positioned(
                    left: position.dx,
                    top: position.dy,
                    child: BackdropFilter(
                      filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                        sigmaX: 10,
                        sigmaY: 10,
                      ),
                      child: ImageFiltered(
                        imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(
                          sigmaX: 10,
                          sigmaY: 10,
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: widget.iconBgColor,
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),
                          width: 40,
                          height: 40,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                /// Card rest of the contents
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                              color: widget.iconBgColor,
                            ),
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            child: Icon(
                              widget.icon,
                              size: 40,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const Icon(Icons.add),
                        ],
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 32),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                              text: '\$${widget.price}\n',
                              style:
                                  widget.theme.textTheme.displaySmall?.copyWith(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                              children: [
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: '${widget.percent}% This week',
                                  style: widget.theme.textTheme.bodyLarge
                                      ?.copyWith(color: Colors.white38),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          if (widget.showChart)
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 32.0),
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.show_chart_outlined,
                                size: 54,
                                color: widget.iconBgColor,
                              ),
                            )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

- see the output at (https://dartpad.dev/?id=e75b493dae1287757c5e1d77a0dc73f1)

Below are the app running in windows and chrome

[Browser App Debug output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKIsd.png)

[Windows app debug output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke3XM.png)

Blur effect is good in chrome. It should be solved in windows. Windows effect is very weird.